# How to cache a request for a while?

Tags: javascript, request, http-headers

I have function that gives required request parameters such as API path, method, body, params and makes a request (the function uses JavaScript `fetch` function). There are some APIs that return big JSON data and I want to cache those requests for a while. I know it is possible to cache a request with specific HTTP headers but have not idea how to set cache it from client side.

I tried this

```js
let cache = null;
let timeout = null;
let cacheDelay = 2000;

function request(path, method = "GET", body = {}, allowCache = false) {
    cache = allowCache ? "force-cache" : null;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        cache = null;
    }, cacheDelay);
    
    let options = {method};
    if (method !== "GET") options.body = JSON.stringify(body);
    if (cache) options.cache = cache;
    
    return fetch(path, options);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to mention, what's wrong with your attempt...

Comment: @vanowm, It does not work properly if I cache different requests asynchronously.

Comment: "does not work properly" as in...what _exactly_ is wrong?

Comment: @vanowm, when I send a request on first API caching that, then trying to send non-cached request it also sent cached as the 2 sec did not passed yet.